# How to generate a pdf report in adempiere through WebServices?

Tags: java, web-services, pdf, adempiere, idempiere

I'm working with Adempiere in its new version iDempiere. I have a web application in Java using the erp web services implementation but in this moment i dont know how to call a web service that execute the print process of a Purchase Order (I called web services to generate the Purchase Order) and get the PDF.

There is a few documentation!

Can anybody help me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

We can get the pdf file after completion of the purchase order.

This you can achieve through configurations. but it sends a mail. 
For this purpose you need to extend(modify) the workflow of the process_order

Process_order :- ( This workflow used for Purchase order and sales order ) 
default system already have 4 nodes ( Start, prepare, complete ).

1. Now you need to create one more node i.e send mail and select Action as Email
2. And open Complete node And open the transition tab . and select the Send Mail node in transition.

If you don't want send an email then you can simply call createPDF method using MOrder object in your web-service class at the end.